# import of svg file in js file not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am working on a frontend project with html js and css. i have installed parcel so that i can use sass files. i have done things like npm init where duplicate files were created so that i can run on browser. the problem is i imported svg file in js file. when i console.log for the imported file it is shown on console of browser. but the changes is not shown on screen, there are no icons added.

i tried clearing cache nothing worked also imported the file in different ways possible

Comment: how do u show the svg? do u use an img tag with src attribute?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to download `svg` on your local machine and then add that to your `project`.
Import that in your main file like `App.js` .

```
   import React from 'react';
import ReactLogo from './logo.svg';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReactLogo />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

And if you want to add through a link try this:

```
import ReactLogo from './logo.svg';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <img src={ReactLogo} alt="React Logo" />
    </div>
  );
}

<img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg..." alt="React Logo" />
```